# multiple same jobs created with same name and group - Quartz

Tags: java, scheduler, jobs

Hi I'm doing portlet on Liferay that create jobs and when I launch this portlet create the job with the same name and group. Should not fail the creation when a new job is created with the same name and group? 
My problem now is that I have multiple jobs doing the same.

I create the jobs with this method:

```
   public void pruebaTrigger() throws Exception{


    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(SimpleJob.class)
    .withIdentity("dummyJobName", "group1").build();


    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
    .newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1")
    .withSchedule(
        CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *"))
    .build();

    //schedule it
    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

}
```

The other question is: How I can stop jobs of actually jobs running?

Thanks for the info,
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String groupName : scheduler.getJobGroupNames()) {
   for (JobKey jobKey :
   scheduler.getJobKeys(GroupMatcher.jobGroupEquals(groupName))) { 
   JobDetail job=scheduler.getJobDetail(jobKey);
   scheduler.deleteJob(job.getKey());
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.